# XML DTD - What does the asterisk mean when it's outside the bracket

Tags: xml, dtd

I understand that

```
    <!ELEMENT tagname (source*)>
```

means that source can appear zero or more times, but I don't understand what this means

```
     <!ELEMENT story (#PCDATA | date)*>
```

Is that asterisk outside the bracket applied to everything inside or to story or something else?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It's a (possibly empty) sequence over `{ #PCDATA | date }`. To be clear a production rule for `(x|y)*` is

```
(x|y)* = {} | x(x|y)* | y(x|y)*
```

In your language of "zero or more times" it means that you repeatedly choose one of `#PCDATA` or `date` where you make zero or more choices.

Clear?